Debian 12: ping works but dig/curl don't
Sorry if I post something solved on other thread, but I think I am not. I have read several similar issues but to no avail so far.
Basically my connection worked perfectly since I installed from scratch Debian 12, 15 days ago. Worked well, both wired and wifi. Yesterday I installed Mozilla's Firefox instead of Debian's Firefox to improve speed. At the same time, my VPN was having login problems, but it ended logging ok.
Mozilla's Firefox was working ok, but suddenly it stopped. My research so far:
ping works
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=9.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=9.60 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=9.83 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=9.91 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.601/9.803/9.910/0.119 ms

nmcli is apparently ok for wired connection, including DNS servers. I have dropped wifi by now to focus:
$ nmcli
enp0s31f6: conectado to Wired connection 1
        "Intel I219-V"
        ethernet (e1000e), 54:E1:AD:D2:E5:34, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 predeterminado
        inet4 212.128.174.173/21
        inet4 212.128.173.151/21
        route4 212.128.168.0/21 metric 100
        route4 default via 212.128.168.1 metric 100
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
        inet6 fe80::56e1:adff:fed2:e534/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

lo: connected (externally) to lo
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
        inet4 127.0.0.1/8
        inet6 ::1/128

wlp4s0: desconectado
        "Intel 8265 / 8275"
        wifi (iwlwifi), E6:46:B6:02:F4:66, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlp4s0: desconectado
        "p2p-dev-wlp4s0"
        wifi-p2p, hw

cdc-wdm0: no disponible
        "cdc-wdm0"
        gsm (cdc_mbim), hw

DNS configuration:
        servers: 212.128.130.140 212.128.130.141
        domains: ---- (is ok, but not shown for privacy)
        interface: enp0s31f6

Actually, I can dig a URL via a DNS server:
$ dig @212.128.130.140 linuxconfig.org

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian <<>> @212.128.130.140 linuxconfig.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29008
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1410
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;linuxconfig.org.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
linuxconfig.org.        300     IN      A       172.66.40.244
linuxconfig.org.        300     IN      A       172.66.43.12

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 212.128.130.140#53(212.128.130.140) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 18 10:26:44 CEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76

But I cannot curl or browse:
$ curl linuxconfig.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: linuxconfig.org

My etc/resolv.conf is empty, just a comment of "#Generated by NetworkManager". Not sure if it is used anymore in Debian 12. Anyways, I cannot edit it even with sudo.
So, that's how far I reached by now. I haven't found anything remarkable in the logs, but maybe I'm not looking ok. Any clues?
Thanks a lot!!!

Results for ping -c3 1.1.1.1 and ping -c3 google.com and host google.com will help show you if it's a DNS issue or a routing issue. (Yes no no → DNS. No no no → Routing)

Thanks Chris. It's a "yes no no", so apparently a DNS issue, but nmcli returns correctly the DNS information, and dig also works fine given de DNS.
What can be wrong then?

Your resolv.conf should not be empty - there should be atleast one nameserver entry. Try adding one as a test, like nameserver 8.8.8.8

The thing is that I cannot edit /etc/resolv.conf, how could this be? I cannot edit it with sudo or root, or change the privileges (operation not permitted error). It has -rw-r--r-- 1 root root. That's weird.

@Jude - regarding the "removed for privacy"... ¿Te das cuenta de que cualquiera de las IPs que quedan, incluso sin el «search domains», apuntan a la facultad de derecho de la universidad de Salamanca?  ;)

Solved!
Apparently, resolv.conf was changed to empty and immutable.
I solved it by:
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

I did not require to edit resolv.conf, NetworkManager did it on restart.
What I don't understand is how that could happen? Maybe an attack or virus?
Thanks for the help!

Maybe you did it a while ago?
